# Difference between std::ifstream::is_open and std::ios::good

Tags: c++, io, std, fstream

If we are working with `std::ifstream`, when do we call `std::ifstream::is_open()` and when `std::ios::good()` ? What is the difference?.  Example code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "Test.txt";
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    if(!file.good())
        std::cout << "file not good" << std::endl;

    if(!file.is_open())
        std::cout << "file not open" << std::endl;

...
}
```

Comment: In that context both are the same, but `is_open()` is more explicit. Later after you have read some data, `good()` could be false (perhaps because you have attempted to read past the end of file) but `is_open()` would still be true.

Comment: Take a look at the table at the bottom of this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate There are a lot of scenarios where the file can be open and not be good. Usually you're more likely to work with `fail()`, `bad()` and `eof()` or the bool-related operators through...

Comment: I don't do either. `if (file) { /* use it */ }`.